# Not skipping empty lines in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to replicate a file without the 1st line.
But I can't seem to copy it's contents properly.

This is how I tried:

```
for /f "tokens=* skip=1" %%i in (input.txt) do (
    echo %%i >> "output.txt"
)
```

When my **input.txt** have this:

```
test1

1. test item1

2. test item2

3. test item3
```

It gives me this:

```
1. test item1    
2. test item2
3. test item3
```

**Expected Output:**

```
1. test item1

2. test item2

3. test item3
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q47067655.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

(FOR /f "tokens=1*skip=1delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n /r ".*" "%filename1%"') DO ECHO(%%b)>"%outfile%1"
(FOR /f "tokens=1*skip=1delims=]" %%a IN ('find /n /v "" ^<"%filename1%"') DO ECHO(%%b)>"%outfile%2"
(more +1 "%filename1%">"%outfile%3")

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.
You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q47067655.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the files defined as %outfile%*

`for /f` will skip empty lines, so ensure the lines are not empty by numbering them.

Note that `echo(%%a` will produce an empty line with empty `%%a`

Your example output omits the blank line between the `skip`ped line and the next.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with `for /f`, the documentation from `for /?` is quite adamant:

> ***Blank lines are skipped.***

For a *simple* need like this, it can be met with the Windows `more` program, which can start at an arbitrary line and will not actually page the file if it's redirected (up to a certain size anyway). That means your entire script can be replaced with a single command:

```
c:\users\paxdiablo> more +2 input.txt >output.txt
c:\users\paxdiablo> type output.txt
1. test item1

2. test item2

3. test item3
```

For more *complex* tasks or if your files are bigger than what `more` can handle without paging, you should probably stop using (the frankly brain-dead) older Windows tools and switch instead to PowerShell.

Or get yourself some decent text processing tools for Windows such as `sed` or `awk` (see [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html)), after which you can just do something like (for your case, though the script can now be arbitrarily complex):

```
c:\users\paxdiablo> awk "NR>2{print}" input.txt >output.txt
```

Comment: The `more` command also has its faults. It will automatically pause and wait for user input at line 65534.

Comment: Another of which is that the **`More`** command always deletes tabs. It defaults to replacing each with 8 spaces, but the number of spaces can be changed using it's **`/T`** option.